# Pre Order Traversal Base Case

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a pre order traversal algorithm that follows the pre traversal pattern and along the way gets the element and pastes it into an ArrayList to be returned to the console.

Here is what I have determined so far.

1. This is a question of iteration, I need to keep iterating the tree using methods to get and return the elements.
2. I need a base case to terminate the iteration of the methods and return the array list.
3. I will need two methods, one to check the base case and if not fulfilled activate another method to iterate and place the element into the array list.

What I am really struggling to determine is what should be the base case? At first I thought well if I can't getRight() and can't getParent().getRight() then I must have no more nodes to check, but with a large tree with so many levels this logically does not work. Then I thought I can use a counter, when I check and get the element of a node I can increment a counter and check that with the size to cancel the continued iteration but then I tried it and it was very problematic so much so I figured this cannot be right.

How should I set up my two methods to accomplish this and more importantly what should I use as a base case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using recursion here, not iteration. The algorithm is really quite straightforward then:

```
public void preorder(Node n, ArrayList<String> elementAccumulator) {
  elementAccumulator.add(n.getValue());
  if(n.getLeft() != null) { preorder(n.getLeft(), elementAccumulator); }
  if(n.getRight() != null) { preorder(n.getRight(), elementAccumulator); }

}
```

Comment: Follow up question, what if I had a very big tree wouldn't this just trickle down to the bottom and get stuck. I assume at some point you have to move a node back up the tree and then move to the next node on the right. [I've drawn a very poor diagram, ](https://prnt.sc/iva39y) in this context how would I move back up a step to access the L, J, etc nodes. I am not too experienced with data structures and algorithms forgive my ignorance or any mistakes. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RhodriMorgan Use a debugger and see what this does, and how the "moving up again" is solved. After you have understood, read up on recursion, dynamic programming and functional programming. It will change the way you look at problems/programs.